# Issue getting fault message from message context in Masstransit

Tags: masstransit

I have an application that needs to intercept the current message consume context and extract a value that is defined in a base interface. That value is a tenant code that is eventually used in an EF database context.

I have a provider that takes a MassTransit ConsumerContext, and then using `context.TryGetMessage()`, extracts the tenant code, which is ultimately used to switch database contexts to a specific tenant database.

The issue lies in the MessageContextTenantProvider below. If a non-fault message is consumed then `ConsumeContext<IBaseEvent>` works fine. However if it is a fault, `ConsumeContext<Fault<IBaseEvent>>` doesn't work as expected.

Durring debugging I can see that the message context for a fault is `ConsumeContext<Fault<IVerifyEvent>>`, but why doesn't it work with a base interface as per the standard message? Of course, `ConsumeContext<Fault<IVerifiedEvent>>` works fine, but I have a lot of message types, and I don't want to have to define them all in that tenant provider.

Any ideas?

```
public interface ITenantProvider
{
    string GetTenantCode();
}

public class MessageContextTenantProvider : ITenantProvider
{
    private readonly ConsumeContext _consumeContext;

    public MessageContextTenantProvider(ConsumeContext consumeContext)
    {
        _consumeContext = consumeContext;
    }

    public string GetTenantCode()
    {
        // get tenant from message context
        if (_consumeContext.TryGetMessage(out ConsumeContext<IBaseEvent> baseEvent))
        {
            return baseEvent.Message.TenantCode; // <-- works for the non fault consumers
        }

        // get tenant from fault message context
        if (_consumeContext.TryGetMessage<Fault<IBaseEvent>>(out var gebericFaultEvent))
        {
            return gebericFaultEvent.Message.Message.TenantCode; // <- doesn't work generically
        }

        // get tenant from fault message context (same as above)
        if (_consumeContext.TryGetMessage(out ConsumeContext<Fault<IBaseEvent>> faultEvent))
        {
            return faultEvent.Message.Message.TenantCode; // <= generically doesn't work when using the base interface?
        }

        // get tenant from specific concrete fault class
        if (_consumeContext.TryGetMessage(out ConsumeContext<Fault<IVerifiedEvent>> verifiedFaultEvent))
        {
            return verifiedFaultEvent.Message.Message.TenantCode; // <-- this works
        }

        // not able to extract tenant
        return null;
    }
}

public partial class VerificationDbContext
{
    string connectionString;

    public string ConnectionString
    {
        get
        {
            if (connectionString == null)
            {
                string tenantCode = _tenantProvider.GetTenantCode();
                connectionString = _tenantConnectionManager.GetConnectionString(orgId);
            }
            return connectionString;
        }
    }

    private readonly ITenantProvider _tenantProvider;

    private readonly ITenantConnectionManager _tenantConnectionManager;

    public VerificationDbContext(ITenantProvider tenantProvider, ITenantConnectionManager tenantConnectionManager)
    {
        _tenantProvider = tenantProvider;
        _tenantConnectionManager = tenantConnectionManager;
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.ConnectionString))
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=VerificationDb;Integrated Security=True")
                .ConfigureWarnings((warningBuilder) => warningBuilder.Ignore(RelationalEventId.AmbientTransactionWarning));
        }
        else
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(this.ConnectionString)
                .ConfigureWarnings((warningBuilder) => warningBuilder.Ignore(RelationalEventId.AmbientTransactionWarning));
        }
    }
}

public interface ITenantConnectionManager
{
    string GetConnectionString(string tenantCode);
}

public class TenantConnectionManager : ITenantConnectionManager
{
    private ITenantRepository _tenantRepository;

    public TenantConnectionManager(ITenantRepository tenantRepository)
    {
        _tenantRepository = tenantRepository;
    }

    public string GetConnectionString(string tenantCode)
    {
        return _tenantRepository.GetByTenantCode(tenantCode).ConnectionString;
    }
}

public interface IBaseEvent
{
    string TenantCode { get; }
}

public interface IVerifiedEvent : IBaseEvent
{
    string JobReference { get; }
}

public class VerifiedEventConsumer : IConsumer<IVerifiedEvent>
{
    private readonly IVerifyCommand _verifyCommand;

    private readonly ITenantProvider _tenantProvider;

    public VerifiedEventConsumer(ITenantProvider tenantProvider, IVerifyCommand verifyCommand)
    {
        _verifyCommand = verifyCommand;
        _tenantProvider = tenantProvider;
    }

    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<IVerifiedEvent> context)
    {
        await _verifyCommand.Execute(new VerifyRequest
        {
            JobReference = context.Message.JobReference,
            TenantCode = context.Message.TenantCode
        });
    }
}

public class VerifiedEventFaultConsumer : IConsumer<Fault<IVerifiedEvent>>
{
    private readonly IVerifyFaultCommand _verifyFaultCommand;

    private readonly ITenantProvider _tenantProvider;

    public CaseVerifiedEventFaultConsumer(ITenantProvider tenantProvider, IVerifyFaultCommand verifyFaultCommand)
    {
        _verifyFaultCommand = verifyFaultCommand;
        _tenantProvider = tenantProvider;
    }

    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<Fault<ICaseVerifiedEvent>> context)
    {
        await _verifyFaultCommand.Execute(new VerifiedFaultRequest
        {
            JobReference = context.Message.Message.JobReference,
            Exceptions = context.Message.Exceptions
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Same problem over here. MassTransit Fault only sends event for top-level interface. I was wondering if this is a bug and if there is a workaround.

Comment: @fantastischIdee I solved this. See below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the issue by using the GreenPipes TryGetPayload extension method:

```
public class MessageContextTenantProvider : ITenantProvider
{
    private readonly ConsumeContext _consumeContext;

    public MessageContextTenantProvider(ConsumeContext consumeContext)
    {
        _consumeContext = consumeContext;
    }

    public string GetTenantCode()
    {
        // get tenant from message context
        if (_consumeContext.TryGetMessage(out ConsumeContext<IBaseEvent> baseEvent))
        {
            return baseEvent.Message.TenantCode;
        }

        // get account code from fault message context using Greenpipes
        if (_consumeContext.TryGetPayload(out ConsumeContext<Fault<IBaseEvent>> payloadFaultEvent))
        {
            return payloadFaultEvent.Message.Message.TenantCode;
        }

        // not able to extract tenant
        return null;
    }
}
```